# Zencart Homepage Customization

Tags: php, html, zen-cart

I am customizing a  zen-cart template. 
I want to edit newProduct, FeaturedProduct section, but I can not understand which files should be edited.

I know I can style them with css, but I want to change the html table structure into html unordered list structure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to edit the centerbox section, and not sideboxes or new/featured pages, you need to edit includes/modules/new_products.php and includes/modules/featured_products.php (it might also be inside your custom template folder so make sure you check if the override file exists inside includes/modules/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME/ directory).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got how it works. Do you know how to disable some sidebox by default?